# JSON escaping in Logstash

Tags: java, json, logstash, kibana

I am sending some JSON data from Java server via TCP to Logstash (Logstash sends them to Elasticsearch) and these JSON data seems to be escaped in Elastic.

Java serialization:

```
Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
jsonMap.put("age", event.getAge());
for (Entry<String, Serializable> attribute : event.getAttributes().entrySet()) {
    jsonMap.put("attribute_" + attribute.getKey(), attribute.getValue());
}
jsonMap.put("message", event.getMessage());
jsonMap.put("cause", event.getCause());
jsonMap.put("timestamp", event.getTimestamp());
jsonMap.put("eventid", event.getEventId());
jsonMap.put("instanceid", event.getInstanceId());
jsonMap.put("origin", event.getOrigin());
jsonMap.put("severity", event.getSeverity());
jsonMap.put("durability", event.getDurability());
jsonMap.put("detail", event.getDetail());
int i = 0;
for (String tag : event.getTags()) {
    jsonMap.put("tag_" + String.valueOf(i), tag);
    i++;
}

return new JSONObject(jsonMap).toString();
```

Java Socket:

```
try (Socket clientSocket = new Socket(url, port);
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
        clientSocket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8")) {
    out.write(content.toString());
    out.flush();
}
```

Example data in Elastic:

```
"message": "{\"detail\":null,\"cause\":null,\"attribute_start\":\"Mon Jan 11 16:15:28 CET 2016\",\"durability\":\"MOMENTARY\",\"attribute_login\":\"\",\"origin\":\"fortuna.ws.navipro\",\"severity\":\"ERROR\",\"attribute_type\":null,\"attribute_methodName\":\"Logout\",\"eventid\":\"ws.navipro.call\",\"attribute_call\":\"[57,7256538816272415441,,OK]{0 connections} CZ() Calling method 'Logout' at 1452525329029(Mon Jan 11 16:15:28 CET 2016-Mon Jan 11 16:15:29 CET 2016; roundtrip=36ms):\\n\\tRequest\\n\\t\\tCLASS com.etnetera.projects.jnp.fortuna.navipro.ws.ClientLogoutRequest\\n\\t\\tkeep: true\\n\\t\\tCLASS com.etnetera.projects.jnp.fortuna.navipro.ws.RequestBody\\n\\t\\tcountry: CZ\\n\\t\\tsessionCC: NULL\\n\\t\\tsessionID:\\n\\t\\tsessionIP:\\n\\t\\tdebug: NULL\\n\\t\\tns: NULL\\n\\t\\tCLASS com.etnetera.projects.jnp.fortuna.navipro.ws.RequestCorpus\\n\\tResponse\\n\\t\\tCLASS com.etnetera.projects.jnp.fortuna.navipro.ws.ClientLogoutResponse\\n\\t\\tCLASS com.etnetera.projects.jnp.fortuna.navipro.ws.ResponseBody\\n\\t\\tCLASS com.etnetera.projects.jnp.fortuna.navipro.ws.ResponseCorpus\\n\\t\\tmessage: \\n\\t\\t[1] \\n\\t\\t\\tCLASS com.etnetera.projects.jnp.fortuna.navipro.ws.Message\\n\\t\\t\\tparam: \\n\\t\\t\\t[1] \\n\\t\\t\\t\\tCLASS com.etnetera.projects.jnp.fortuna.navipro.ws.Message$Param\\n\\t\\t\\t\\tindex: 0\\n\\t\\t\\t\\ttype: NULL\\n\\t\\t\\t\\tvalue: 3\\n\\t\\t\\tid: 104\\n\\t\\t\\tseverity: NOTIFICATION\\n\\t\\t\\tlink: NULL\\n\\t\\tentryLink: NULL\\n\\t\\thint: NULL\\n\\t\\thintType: NULL\\n\\t\\tstatus: OK\\nEND\",\"timestamp\":1452525329030,\"message\":\"NaviPro method Logoutcalled.\",\"tag_1\":\"NaviPro\",\"attribute_end\":\"Mon Jan 11 16:15:29 CET 2016\",\"attribute_sessionId\":\"\",\"age\":0,\"tag_0\":\"Logout\",\"instanceid\":\"Logout\",\"attribute_address\":\""}"
```

Logstash config:

```
input {
  syslog {
    port => 1514
  }
  tcp {
    port => 3333
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "docker" {
    json {
      source => "message"
    }
    mutate {
      rename => [ "log", "message" ]
    }
    date {
      match => [ "time", "ISO8601" ]
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
  }
}
```

I want to have data in Elastic as JSON so I can filter fields in Kibana.

EDIT:

If I try to change configuration to this:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 3333
    codec => json
  }
}
```

Logstash refuses to launch with this line in log:

```
logstash_1 | {:timestamp=>"2016-01-13T10:13:58.583000+0000", :message=>"SIGTERM received. Shutting down the pipeline.", :level=>:warn}
```

Comment: I think Java is escaping the string, not LogStash

Comment: I am also suspecting this. But in Eclipse in debug mode String is shown as not escaped. I have also tried different libraries for JSON serialization but nothing worked. I suspect that writing to outputstream is causing the escaping. Do you have any idea how to send String through tcp without escaping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was in incorrect Logstash configuration. Logstash was running but not sending anything through filter. This is correct configuration:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 3333
    type => "java"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "java" {
    json {
      source => "message"
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! even without the "type".

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple test and all you should need to add to your logstash configuration is `codec => json`. The default value is `"line"` and will escape the characters in the string.

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 3333
    codec => json
  }
}

output {
  stdout { 
    codec => rubydebug 
  }

  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I have already tried that. Now nothing is pushed to Elastic through Logstash.

Comment: Hmm. I don't see why making this change would do that. Did you keep the port number the same, logstash and elasticsearch are running, and you ran your app?

Comment: Yes, I tried debugging and TCP message is send successfully, Kibana is running but is not showing any data since I restarted Logstash with added configuration. (Kibana is showing older data so Elastic is also running)

Comment: Can you add an stdout to rubydebug in the logstash config and try again?

Comment: Did you replace your existing input section or replace the whole logstash file? And that error log message isn't very descriptive...

Comment: I have just added codec => json line to tcp section. Yea, I know. Googling error didn't help much. Is there anyway to make Logstash tell me more?

Comment: I have updated my question with exactly what I tested. As long as your congiuration file is fine. Then the only reasons I can think of that it would fail is if logstash was already running, it couldn't bind to port 3333, or maybe it couldn't communicate with elasticsearch